# .NET MAUI cuts off top left of my ImageButton when using <Border> StrokeShape="Ellipse"

Tags: c#, windows, border, maui

This is my first time programming with .NET MAUI 7.0. I'm using a Windows Machine. When using the following code, part of the image is cut off in the top left.

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="80" StrokeShape="Ellipse">
    <ImageButton Source="image.png" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</Border>
```

[image cutout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f4Wy.png)

I've encountered the same problem when using StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 40,40,40,40". I need the image to be complete rather than being cut out in the top left.

Comment: I used an icon to test, but I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please share the icon you used here so that I can try to reproduce this problem on my side?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in iOS which was fixed in .NET 8, more information can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17753

I am not sure why do you want to use a Border on an ImageButton if this is just to make it Circular you can do this instead:

```
<ImageButton 
HeightRequest="50"
BackgroundColor="White"
WidthRequest="50"
CornerRadius="25"/>
```

The trick is corner radius should be half of Height and Width.